# Moving text to right side CSS

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I'm facing a problem using CSS. I've expended the time allotted to complete the target job, but it's too hard for me. Now I'm going ask all of you (webmasters/developers) to solve my problem.

[image: sidebar urgentfiles.com]

Please review this picture and tell me how I can move the second line of text for the bullets numbered (3, 5, 6, 8) - I want the second line of text to start at the same horizontal position at which the first one starts.

Here is CSS of this sidebar:

```
.plugins ul{padding-left:0;counter-reset:plugincount;}

.plugins ul li{border-bottom:1px dashed #ddd;line-height:20px}

.plugins ul li:before{content:counter(plugincount);counter-increment:plugincount;margin-left:-10px;margin-right:1px;background:#8FC93E;border-radius:25px;border:1px solid #000;color:#fff;font:bold 16px georgia;padding:.3em .6em}

..plugins ul li{border-bottom:1px dashed #ddd}

.plugins ul li a{margin-left:10px;}

.plugins ul li a:hover{text-decoration:none}

.plugins ul li:hover,.plugins ul li:hover{border-bottom:1px dashed #696969}
```

Here is the original link of site: [Urgentfiles.com](http://www.urgentfiles.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the bullets be outside the `li` content:

```
ul li { list-style-position: outside; margin-left: 1em; }
```

Comment: I'don't get your answer so please explain it

Comment: Did you try the code? When bullets are created, they have either the default `inside` or `outside` positioning of the actual black circle bullet. This refers to it's position relative to the `li` element. If it's inside, then it's just like a letter within the bullet's text. If it's outside, then the left aligned text starts to the right of the dark circle.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/jhkb5jrb/1/

```
body {
  counter-reset: my-counter; /* REmove this */
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 300px;
   counter-reset:plugincount; /* Add this */
}
ul li:before {
    background: #8fc93e;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    content:counter(plugincount); /* change from my-counter to plugincount*/
    counter-increment:plugincount; /* change from my-counter to plugincount*/        
    float: left;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 0.3em 0.6em;
    position: relative;
}
ul li{        
    padding: 0.7em 0;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: you've done wrong because I've lost the automatic numbering :D

Comment: Well this is how to solve the problem with the text positioning, you can add your own counter instead of my-counter :) I have not done wrong, you wanted a solution for a particular problem and the problem is gone  :)

Comment: yes you'r right problem is gone alongwith my counter :)

Comment: Let me know if the changes work and in future don't copy paste solutions if you don't know what you are doing, especially on a live site :)

Comment: You didn't change the counter it still says my-counter. Change all instances of my-counter to plugincount. See the updated answer :)

Comment: I am wasting your time trying to help you ? Goodbye :)

Answer (score 0):

if you should maintain this markup

set

```
.plugins ul li {position: relative; padding-left:40px /* set padding bigger then circle */;
.plugins ul li::before {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; margin:0 /*clear margin*/
```

but I think change html markup is better